# How to use GraphQL Schema Stitching with Elixir Absinthe?

Tags: elixir, schema, graphql, microservices, absinthe

To be developed and deployed independently we want to decompose our schema into separate microservices within Erlang ecosystem using Elixir Absinthe, but it seems that they don't have ready this feature yet. So my question is.

Is it posible using Elixir Absinthe to create a single GraphQL schema from multiple underlying GraphQL APIs?